# Microsoft Edge - Developer tools/console not showing up

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge, developer-tools

Like the title says, the Dev Tools in MS Edge are not working for me. I have a clean installation of Windows 10 and when i open the Edge explorer, go to any site and hit F12, nothing but a blank window shows up.

I have tried a reinstallation according to this: https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-reinstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10/ , but it didn't help, still same issue.

[image: Screenshot of Edge with missing developer's tools]

Has anyone any idea how to fix this?

- Windows 10 Home
- Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0
- Microsoft EdgeHTML
  17.17134

---

#### UPDATE 20/09/2018

This problem is still persisting ... behaving the same as described above.

- Last Windows Update: **KB4457128**
- Current Edge version: 42.17134.1.0 (still the same)